# A curve whose normalization is $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By curve I mean a reduced, irreducible, projective variety of dimensional 1 over an algebraically closed field $k$ (you may assume $char( k) =0$), in particular, it might be singular. Let $X$ be a curve such that its normalization is $\mathbb{P}^1$, then what kind of curves could $X$ be? If $X$ is smooth, then $X$ must be $\mathbb{P}^1$ by Hurwitz's theorem. But I don't know how to deal with singular case, is there any kind of Hurwitz's theorem for singular curves?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve#Rational_curves by this I mean it is a large class of curves. Their generic name can help you find more about them.

Comment: @RGB could you elaborate on how does this article related to my question? For example, could you give me one such curve which is not $\mathbb{P}^1$? I felt that the only possibility is $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we take $X:=(zx^2-y^3=0)\subset\mathbb{P}^2$. The curve is contained in the charts where $x\neq0$ and $z\neq0$.

In the chart where $x\neq0$we have coordinates $u=z/x$ and $v=y/x$ and we can write the defining equation as $u-v^3=0$. So, it is smooth there.

In the chart where $z\neq0$ we have coordinates $u=x/z$ and $v=y/z$ and we can write it as $u^2-v^3=0$ which has a singularity only at $u=v=0$. So, this curve is not smooth and therefore not isomorphic (biregular) to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

We can define $f:\mathbb{P}^1\dashrightarrow X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ by taking, say from the $x\neq0$ chart in $\mathbb{P}^1$ in which we have coordinate $t=y/x$, $f(t)=[1:t^3:t^2]$. This is regular on the complement of the point $[0,1]\in\mathbb{P}^1$ (then rational).

In the complement of $y=0$ in $X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ it has the inverse $[x:y:z]\mapsto[1:x/y]$, which is rational. This sends the point $[1:t^3:t^2]$ to $[1:t]$.

Therefore $X$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I cannot appreciate more!